# swipe to verify fail in puppteer-sharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I have been battling with this issue on swiping the slider. Everything works fine its when I swipe ther slide I get the error as shown in the image. below is my attempted code.

[image]

```
 class Program
    {
        private const string username = "username";
        private const string password = "password";

        public static async Task GetStarted()
        {

            //await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision).ConfigureAwait(false);
            using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = false,
                ExecutablePath = @"C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\chrome-win\chrome-win\chrome.exe",
                DefaultViewport = ViewPortOptions.Default
            }
            ).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                var page = await browser.NewPageAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                await page.GoToAsync("https://c2c.huobi.br.com/vi-vi/login/").ConfigureAwait(false);
                await page.TypeAsync(@"input[name='login_name']", username).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await page.TypeAsync(@"input[name='password']", password).ConfigureAwait(false);

                ElementHandle button = await page.QuerySelectorAsync(".login-btn").ConfigureAwait(false);
                await button.FocusAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                await page.Keyboard.PressAsync("Enter").ConfigureAwait(false);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                ElementHandle sliderElement = await page.QuerySelectorAsync(".slidetounlock").ConfigureAwait(false);

                var slider = await sliderElement.BoundingBoxAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                var sliderHandle = await page.QuerySelectorAsync(".nc_iconfont.btn_slide").ConfigureAwait(false);
                var handle = await sliderHandle.BoundingBoxAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                await page.Mouse.MoveAsync(handle.X = handle.Width / 2, handle.Y + handle.Height / 2).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await page.Mouse.DownAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                await page.Mouse.MoveAsync(handle.X = slider.Width, handle.Y + handle.Height /2).ConfigureAwait(false);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await GetStarted().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting that error even sliding manually. I think the captcha tool is detecting the browser is being automated.

Comment: Another note: You posted a user and password here.

Comment: Any solution please